# Why AudioContext.createMediaElementSource seems to break the playback on iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari, web-audio-api

I am creating a React application, where I want to use WebAudio API. I have a component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MdPlayArrow from 'react-icons/lib/md/play-arrow';

const AudioContext = window.AudioContext // Default
                     || window.webkitAudioContext
                     || false; 

class Player extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.audioContext = new AudioContext();

    this.audioRef.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
      if (this.audioRef&&!isNaN(this.audioRef.duration)) {
        this.audioSource = this.audioContext.createMediaElementSource(this.audioRef);
        this.audioSource.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
      }
    });
  }

  handleOnPlayClick() {
     this.audioRef.play();
  }
  render() {
    return  (
      <div onClick={ this.handleOnPlayClick.bind(this) } >
        <audio src={ this.props.src }
               ref={ ref => { this.audioRef = ref } } />
        <MdPlayArrow />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Player;
```

When handlePlayOnClick fires, the audio is played only for one "note" (less than second, then silence). If I log the variables, the audioSource.mediaElement.currentTime is correct. So, the media element thinks it is playing, but there is no sound.

If I remove the lines where I create the audioSource using AudioContext.createMediaElementSource() and connect it, audio plays properly.

Why using the createMediaElementSource messes the playback/AudioContext?